# presenting elements in ruby on rails from wunderground api wrapper

Tags: ruby, api

noob question, i've got this wrapper https://github.com/wnadeau/wunderground that gets weather data via API from the site wunderground.com
i have tried it out in the rails console and it returns a Json array/hash?
i'm trying to do something like controller:

```
def index
@w_api=Wunderground.new("MY_API_KEY")
w_api.forecast_for("WA","Spokane")

 end

and in my view something like



<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>


        <%  @w_api %>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i don't get anything in my view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with syntax in your view. You've used:

```
<% @w_api %>
```

but to render to view, you need to change it to:

```
<%= @w_api %>
```

`<% %>` just executes the code, but `<%= %>` outputs "result" of the expression.

But, this still may have problems rendering what is stored in your `@w_api`. From your code, I guess you'r trying to debug/see what structure/data is stored in your variable, in that case you should try:

```
<%= p @w_api %>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

thanks, however i did it the wrong way i think..had to change it and remove the @  so it's now

```
w_api=Wunderground.new("MY_API_KEY")
```

but it did'nt give any output so i added

```
@W=w_api.forecast_for("WA","Spokane")
```

why did i have to remove the @?.

in the view i called the @w

```
  <td><%= @w %></td>
```

now i get the result

```
{
    "response"=>{
        "version"=>"0.1",
        "termsofService"=>"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
        "features"=>{
            "forecast"=>1
        }
    },
    "forecast"=>{
        "txt_forecast"=>{
            "date"=>"8:27 AM PST",
            "forecastday"=>[
                {
                    "period"=>0,
                    "icon"=>"partlycloudy",
                    "icon_url"=>"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
                    "title"=>"Thursday",
                    "fcttext"=>"A mix of clouds and sun. High 51F. Winds SSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
                    "fcttext_metric"=>"A mix of clouds and sun. High near 10C. Winds SSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
                    "pop"=>"0"
                },
                {
                    "period"=>1,
                    "icon"=>"nt_clear",
                    "icon_url"=>"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif",
                    "title"=>"Thursday Night",
                    "fcttext"=>"Mostly clear. Low 27F. Winds light and variable.",
                    "fcttext_metric"=>"Mostly clear. Low -2C. Winds light and variable.",
                    "pop"=>"0"
                },
```

however when i go directly to the json API page i get:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "forecast": 1
  }
    }
        ,
    "forecast":{
        "txt_forecast": {
        "date":"4:28 AM PST",
        "forecastday": [
        {
```

the difference is the => and there are no array []

is the first one an object list and the second array? how do i extract the values?
thx!